# Spring boot - logging to file using @PropertySource not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot library module and I want to enable logging into a file.
What I did was to add logging settings in module-conf.properties, but no file is created.

*module-conf.properties*

```
logging.file.name=test.log
```

I also created a configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("...")
@EnableJpaRepositories("...")
@PropertySource("classpath:module-conf.properties")

public class ModuleConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Do I have to configure the logging system the same way I configure the datasource ?

Is there a way avoid manual configuration?

Comment: where is your module-conf.properties file located?

Comment: It is in /src/main/resources/ - the default location. Only the name is changed, to avoid conflict with the application.properties file from the Spring Boot apps where the module is used.

Answer (score 3):

This is interesting!

It appears logging is initialized before the ApplicationContext is created.... and the @PropertySources is read after ApplicationContext is created. As per the documentation, **you can override the config by updating one of the config file based on your logging system**(Spring's default is logback)

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration

Problem:

> Since logging is initialized before the ApplicationContext is created,
> it is not possible to control logging from @PropertySources in Spring
> @Configuration files. The only way to change the logging system or
> disable it entirely is via System properties.

The recommendation:

> When possible, we recommend that you use the -spring variants for
> your logging configuration (for example, logback-spring.xml rather
> than logback.xml). If you use standard configuration locations, Spring
> cannot completely control log initialization.